# View Google Search History without showing my browsing history

Tags: google-search, google-search-history

I am trying to view my Google Search history; unfortunately all of the instructions on how to do this are some variant of go to https://history.google.com/, which gives you past searches and the content you’ve browsed in Chrome and other apps. The problem is, there is so much noise from the browsing history that it's hard to focus in on the search history.

How can I view a copy of just my Google Search History, without history of other sites I've visited?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications community. What is your question ? Please edit your question and make an actual one.

Comment: Question is how to view the Google Search history and exclude browsing history @vas

Comment: @eight I believe it would be better to convert the last sentence to a question since it seems like a conclusion rather than question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view of all the past searches this should get you want you want.

Download a copy of your past searches

- Visit your Web & App Activity page.
- In the top right corner of the
  page, touch Menu More>  Download searches.
- Choose Create Archive.
- When the download is complete, you’ll get an email confirmation with
  a link to the data.

[From the Google directions here.](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6068625?p=ws_history_download&rd=1)

You can see portions of recent searches at `https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard` under **search history** but it's not complete.